# How to link variables so that they cannot both be true or both be false etc.?

Tags: python, oop, variables

Not sure if my question title is correct, please tell me if it isn't so.

Say I have a list, dictionary or tuple of transactions, where the transactions are instances of class. I want to record whether the transaction is pending, completed or cancelled, so I create booleans (within the __init__() of the class) self.completed and self.cancelled (whether it is pending or not can be inferred from both self.completed and self.cancelled being False)

Of course, a transaction cannot be any more than one of the three states at any time, so is there any library to check that only one is true at a time?

I could check this every time I change one of the variables and raise an exception, but I would rather save the lines of code.

I could also have a variable with a integer value of 0, 1, or 2; where 0 is pending, 1 is completed etc. However, this gets rid of the intuitive:

```
    if transaction_a.completed == True: do something
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If they're going to be the opposite of each other no matter what, why do you need 2 separate variables?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want exactly? Also what you have already tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to have a single `status` attribute instead of 3 booleans. You can use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) to represent the different states. You can then make 3 [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that query the `status` attribute:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Status(Enum):
    pending = auto()
    completed = auto()
    cancelled = auto()

class Transaction:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = Status.pending

    @property
    def is_pending(self):
        return self.status == Status.pending

    @property
    def is_completed(self):
        return self.status == Status.completed
```

```
t = Transaction()

print(t.is_pending) # True
t.status = Status.completed
print(t.is_pending) # False
print(t.is_completed) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do that using `xor` like so:

```
class myclass(object):
    """docstring for myclass"""
    def __init__(self, completed=True):
        self.completed = completed
        self.canceled  = self.opposite(self.completed)

    def opposite(self, v):
        return v^v
```

In this way whatever you do, `self.canceled` will always be opposite from `self.completed`.

```
>>> cl = myclass(True)
>>> print cl.completed
True
>>> print cl.canceled
False
```